# Вывести все значения, параметры которых содержат все данные массива

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Дана таблица - object_id и соответствующие ему значения term_taxonomy_id. Написать запрос, который выведет только те object_id, у которых term_taxonomy_id соответствует ВСЕМ значениям полученного массива.

```
$taxonomy; // массив тут некие цифровые значения
$ids = join("','",$taxonomy);
$res=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT `object_id` FROM `wp_term_relationships` WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` IN('$ids')",ARRAY_N);
```

Но этот запрос выводит все object_id, имеющие хотя бы одно значение term_taxonomy_id, равная элементу массива $taxonomy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо добавить такую конструкциюв запрос

```
GROUP BY `object_id` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `term_taxonomy_id`) = $count
```

Вот рабочий код:

```
$taxonomies = [ 1, 26 ]; // массив тут некие цифровые значения.
$ids        = join( ',', $taxonomies );
$count      = count( $taxonomies );

$res = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT `object_id` FROM `wp_term_relationships` WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` IN($ids) GROUP BY `object_id` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `term_taxonomy_id`) = $count",
    ARRAY_N
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!